Can we publish a Flutter package with a version that is lower than the latest version to pub.dev?
My case is, in my flutter package we are having latest version of '2.0.0'. My Cx reported issue in our older version '1.1.6'. We need to provide patch version of '1.1.7' on pub dev.
My doubt is if i publish '1.1.7' version to pub dev, will my latest version '2.0.0' will get deleted or override by this '1.1.7' version. If so, how should i avoid '2.0.0' to get deleted ?

Publishing a patch version like 1.1.7 to pub.dev will not delete or override your latest version 2.0.0. Pub.dev maintains all versions of your package, so you can have multiple versions available simultaneously.
To ensure that 2.0.0 remains unaffected, simply publish 1.1.7 as a new version. This way, users can choose to use either the latest version 2.0.0 or the patched version 1.1.7 depending on their needs.
